# How can I toggle plus and minus icons with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to toggle the `guide-content` div and change the `+` icon to `-` icon and again `-` to `+` icon. To do this I have this jQuery and HTML:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".collapse").click(function() {
    $(this).parents().next(".guide-content").toggle();
    $(this).text("+");
  }, function() {
    $(this).text("-");
    $(this).parents().next(".guide-content").toggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="guide-collapse">
  <div class="guide-title">
    <h2>アンティーク着物について <span class="collapse">+</span></h2>
  </div>
  <div class="guide-content">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="guide-collapse">
  <div class="guide-title">
    <h2>アンティーク着物について <span class="collapse">+</span></h2>
  </div>
  <div class="guide-content">
  </div>
</div>
```

But it's not changing the icon from + to - and - to +.

Comment: I don't think the `click()` method takes a callback like you've done. https://api.jquery.com/click/

Comment: If you check the [docs](https://api.jquery.com/click/) you will find that `.click()` doesn't work like `.hover()`.

Comment: @ChrisG is there any other way to do this?

Comment: What do you want to accomplish? Do you want to change + to - on click and then - to + on clicking again? Or do you want to change + to - and then automatically change - to + after some time?

Comment: @Mythos on click + to - and then on click - to +

Comment: @Shibbir Okay check my answer.

Comment: Here's my take: https://jsfiddle.net/yt4vbz50/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use CSS to toggle it based on a class.

This will allow you to use an icon for more detail and flexibility.

```
$('body').on('click', '.collapse', function(event) {
    $(this).toggleClass('isActive');
});
```

Comment: best answer and simple to do :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a toggle behaviour, change you JS code to the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".collapse").click(function() {
        $(this).parents().next(".guide-content").toggle();
        if($(this).text() == "+"){
            $(this).text("-");
        }
        else {
          $(this).text("+");
        }
        
    });
});
```

This will change the text to "+" if it is "-" and "-" if it is "+", each time you click.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not entirely sure of your intent, but one strategy is to just use two elements with one hidden and toggle both:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".guide-collapse").click(function() {
    $(this).find('h2 span').toggle();
    $(this).find('.guide-content').slideToggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="guide-collapse">
  <div class="guide-title">
    <h2>アンティーク着物について <span class="collapse">+</span><span class="collapse" style="display: none;">-</span></h2>
  </div>
  <div class="guide-content" style="display: none;">Guide content here.</div>
</div>
<div class="guide-collapse">
  <div class="guide-title">
    <h2>アンティーク着物について <span class="collapse">+</span><span class="collapse" style="display: none;">-</span></h2>
  </div>
  <div class="guide-content" style="display: none;">Guide content here.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `guide-content` div is contained actual content which I need to toggle and also change the icon from + to - and then - to +